# Loading scripts on specific page

Tags: server-load, performance

I tend to place my wp_enqueue_scripts hooks on my functions.php but this ends up piling up scripts across my site.

Which makes more sense?

## 1:

```
function load_slider(){
  global $post;
  if($post->ID == 11746){ //  Load slider on home page
    wp_register_script('start-slidorion', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/slidorion/start.js', array('slidorion', 'jquery','easing') );
    wp_enqueue_script('start-slidorion' );
  }
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider');
```

## 2:

```
function load_slider(){
    wp_register_script('start-slidorion', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/slidorion/start.js', array('slidorion', 'jquery','easing') );
    wp_enqueue_script('start-slidorion' );
} 
global $post;
if($post->ID == 11746){ //  Load slider on home page
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider');
}
```

Comment: I'd say **(1)**

Comment: Actually it's a trick question because both gave me the white screen of death

Answer (score 4, accepted):

method two won't work because no page is loaded yet and $post isn't set when your if check runs.

with method one again $post is not yet set at that point, but this method will work if you use [WordPress conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

```
function load_slider(){
  if( is_page(11746) ){ //  Load slider on home page
    wp_register_script('start-slidorion', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/slidorion/start.js', array('slidorion', 'jquery','easing') );
    wp_enqueue_script('start-slidorion' );
  }
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider');
```

**EDIT** another example using `has_term`:

```
function load_slider(){
    global $post;   
    if( has_term( 'your category', 'category', $post ) ):
        // enqueue your script
    endif;
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider');
```

Comment: Thanks, I would imagine this is a common technique although there are other conditionals that depend on the page meta data. Would it be possible to use something like wp_get_object_terms to check if the page is of a certain taxonomy?

Comment: You can use [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) for that. see edit above.