# How to deregister a jquery version for a specific page?

Tags: jquery

in the effort to fix an issue with my website, I needed to include a specific jQuery version through functions.php in my theme folder, but this leads to some compatibility problem with avada portfolios and other builder elements in some pages. How could I deregister a php script located in functions.php for 5 specific pages? If I delete the script, the portfolios and the other builder element come back to work.

I am sorry but I have a poor knowledge of php...
This below is the code added to functions.php:

```
function add_jq_theme() { wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js', array(), 
'1.0.0', true ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jq_theme' );
```

Thank you a lot for your help,
Tommaso

Comment: Have you tried `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` and enqueue the right version?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, but I don't know how to do it for a specific page

Comment: [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56895/loading-scripts-on-specific-page) is about adding script, but you can replace `wp_register_script` with `wp_deregister_script`.

Comment: A lot of scripts like jQuery are cached by browser unless the coder states different. So, you can forget about loading speed or similar. Let it be, there is no speed question. Or you have a special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested it but this should work with small tweaks:

```
function deregister_script_page_createit() {
    if( is_page( 42 ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_script_page_createit' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much twelvell and all of you guys, this works properly!

Comment: Yes, but what happens when page ID got to be changed when, for example, reanimating the site from the XML backup file? Hard-coded IDs are harmful.